# Include external javascript file in mobile app built using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application, cloudinary

I'm trying to add cloudinary upload widget to my mobile app built using react native.

The documentation for integrating this widget in app says 'Include javascript file in your webpage.'

Is it possible to include this javascript file in react native for a mobile application?

Whatever I could find online talks about including this file in WebView of react native but that would mean a web application for a mobile right? I'm trying to build a mobile application and include this external javascript file in it.

Is it possible to do so? And if so, how would we go about it?

Comment: Have you tried `import`?

Comment: import is throwing this error in console `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.location.search')` even before rendering anything on the simulator.

Comment: I added https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js this to a directory in my src and I did an `import cloudinary from 'path/to/all.js';`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
    uploadWidget = () => {      
        cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: "<cloud_name>", upload_preset: "<upload_preset>", sources:['local','url','facebook','dropbox', 'google_photos'], folder: "test"}, 
            function(error, result){ 
                console.log(error);
        });         
    }
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
      <div>Please update your cloudname and upload preset</div>
      <input type="button" value="click me" onClick={this.uploadWidget}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Widget/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RayStra/gevc4ktm/

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand this because where will I define the HTML id container in a mobile application? This is not a web application, so how would `document.getElementById` work?

Comment: This is a question for React Native, but the answer is for React.